# Trying to GRANT mysql permissions to user but get Access Denied Error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried running the following query from phpmyadmin

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'devbaha'@'localhost';
```

but I got the following error:

1045 - Access denied for user 'cpses_deVMGf17mC'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am using a godaddy linux cpanel (phpmyadmin) hosting account. Is there something I am doing wrong or is this something that can not be done on godaddy?

I also tried running:

```
grant all privileges 
  on devbaha.* 
  to 'myuser'@'localhost' 
  identified by 'mypassword';
```

but received the following error:

1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses_deVMGf17mC'@'localhost' to database 'devbaha'

Anyone have any ideas why I can't get `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'devbaha'@'localhost';` to work?

Comment: the user with which u logged in or accessing the db does not have grant permission. First login as root and provide grant permission to the user cpses_deVMGf17mC

Comment: thanks for the reply. Now I am trying to see if it is even possible to log on as root on my Goddady account. I am calling their tech support now to see what they say.

Comment: apparently I cannot log in as root with my Godaddy acount. So I am guessing that I will not be able to run the Grant File command...

Comment: yes go daddy do not provide the root access and only username password having privileges to create more DB and other privileges.

Comment: From the error message they dont give priviledges for you. You need to contact godaddy about this issue.